# Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am generating a PDF file based on the selected employee ID i was facing an error on the local system while still in development saying that **Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at the/path)**

And then i added these two lines to the php script and it worked fine

**`ob_start();`**

and at the end

**`ob_end_flush();`**

But after hosting it to the live server the error is thrown again

Have reffered the FPDF documn**`ob_end_clean();`** on the beginning of the php script [Documentation Link](https://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q2)

The complete code for this is as follows,

The empleavehis.php page

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pdfemployeeleave'])) {
ob_start();
require('mysql_table.php');

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hr');
$empidinfo=$_REQUEST['empid'];

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
    function Header()
    {
    // Title
        $this->Image('img/prudentialshippinglines.png',15,6,15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
        $this->Cell(0,6,'Short Summary ',0,1,'C');
        $this->Cell(0,6,' ',0,1,'C');
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',15);
        $this->Cell(0,6,'History Of Leaves Taken By The Employee',0,1,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);
    // Ensure table header is printed
        parent::Header();
    }
}

// Connect to database

$pdf = new PDF('L','mm','A4');


//$pdf->AddPage();
// First table: output all columns
// $pdf->Table($link,'select * from employees where EMP_ID = 1');
$pdf->AddPage();
// Second table: specify 3 columns
$pdf->AddCol('Leave_Type',48,'Type');
$pdf->AddCol('LeaveSub_Type',48,'Sub Type');
$pdf->AddCol('Start',48,'Start');
$pdf->AddCol('End',48,'End');
$pdf->AddCol('Remarks',48,'Remarks');
$pdf->AddCol('Status',48,'Status');

$prop = array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
    'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
    'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
    'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table($link,"select Leave_Type,LeaveSub_Type,Start,End,Remarks,Status from holiday where EMP_ID = '".$empidinfo."'",$prop);
//$pdf->Image('img/male.png',10,10,-300);
$fileName = "Leave Summary Of - ".$row['Name'].".pdf";
$pdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The mysql_table.php file

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_MySQL_Table extends FPDF
{
    protected $ProcessingTable=false;
    protected $aCols=array();
    protected $TableX;
    protected $HeaderColor;
    protected $RowColors;
    protected $ColorIndex;

    function Header()
    {
    // Print the table header if necessary
        if($this->ProcessingTable)
            $this->TableHeader();
    }

    function TableHeader()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        $this->SetX($this->TableX);
        $fill=!empty($this->HeaderColor);
        if($fill)
            $this->SetFillColor($this->HeaderColor[0],$this->HeaderColor[1],$this->HeaderColor[2]);
        foreach($this->aCols as $col)
            $this->Cell($col['w'],6,$col['c'],1,0,'C',$fill);
        $this->Ln();
    }

    function Row($data)
    {
        $this->SetX($this->TableX);
        $ci=$this->ColorIndex;
        $fill=!empty($this->RowColors[$ci]);
        if($fill)
            $this->SetFillColor($this->RowColors[$ci][0],$this->RowColors[$ci][1],$this->RowColors[$ci][2]);
        foreach($this->aCols as $col)
            $this->Cell($col['w'],5,$data[$col['f']],1,0,$col['a'],$fill);
        $this->Ln();
        $this->ColorIndex=1-$ci;
    }

    function CalcWidths($width, $align)
    {
    // Compute the widths of the columns
        $TableWidth=0;
        foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
        {
            $w=$col['w'];
            if($w==-1)
                $w=$width/count($this->aCols);
            elseif(substr($w,-1)=='%')
                $w=$w/100*$width;
            $this->aCols[$i]['w']=$w;
            $TableWidth+=$w;
        }
    // Compute the abscissa of the table
        if($align=='C')
            $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
        elseif($align=='R')
            $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
        else
            $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;
    }

    function AddCol($field=-1, $width=-1, $caption='', $align='L')
    {
    // Add a column to the table
        if($field==-1)
            $field=count($this->aCols);
        $this->aCols[]=array('f'=>$field,'c'=>$caption,'w'=>$width,'a'=>$align);
    }
    function Table($link, $query, $prop=array())
        {
        // Execute query
        $res=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($link)."<br>Query: $query");
        // Add all columns if none was specified
        if(count($this->aCols)==0)
        {
            $nb=mysqli_num_fields($res);
            for($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++)
                $this->AddCol();
        }
        // Retrieve column names when not specified
        foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
        {
            if($col['c']=='')
            {
                if(is_string($col['f']))
                    $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst($col['f']);
                else
                    $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst(mysqli_fetch_field_direct($res,$col['f'])->name);
            }
        }
        // Handle properties
        if(!isset($prop['width']))
            $prop['width']=0;
        if($prop['width']==0)
            $prop['width']=$this->w-$this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;
        if(!isset($prop['align']))
            $prop['align']='C';
        if(!isset($prop['padding']))
            $prop['padding']=$this->cMargin;
        $cMargin=$this->cMargin;
        $this->cMargin=$prop['padding'];
        if(!isset($prop['HeaderColor']))
            $prop['HeaderColor']=array();
        $this->HeaderColor=$prop['HeaderColor'];
        if(!isset($prop['color1']))
            $prop['color1']=array();
        if(!isset($prop['color2']))
            $prop['color2']=array();
        $this->RowColors=array($prop['color1'],$prop['color2']);
        // Compute column widths
        $this->CalcWidths($prop['width'],$prop['align']);
        // Print header
        $this->TableHeader();
        // Print rows
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
        $this->ColorIndex=0;
        $this->ProcessingTable=true;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            $this->Row($row);
        $this->ProcessingTable=false;
        $this->cMargin=$cMargin;
        $this->aCols=array();
    }
    }
    ?>
```

As far as I have checked I have not left any whitespaces or word spaces and also have tried setting the following

```
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush(); 
ini_set("session.auto_start", 0);
```

Error Image

[image: Error Description]

The files also doesn't contain **BOM** characters

[image: BOM Character Check]

Comment: Why don't you just follow the message "output started at the/path" and fix that line?

Comment: The original error message includes the file and the line in which the data is output. Sadly you removed exactly this from your quote. But at the end it is that simple to look into that file and line-number and remove the output.

Comment: The error line direct me to line number 271 in fpdf.php which is 



268 function Error($msg)
269 { 270 // Fatal error
271 throw new Exception('FPDF error: '.$msg);
272 }

Comment: Have added the error description to the question

Comment: The same code is working in the local server but not in the live server

Comment: Have altered the question @KenLee

Comment: I guess your scripts are simply saved with a [BOM](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+remove+BOM)

Comment: Please also check whether BOM character(s) is included in your scripts as mentioned by @JanSlabon

Comment: @JanSlabon Checked the file with Notepad++ for the encoding and also did try converting it to UTF8 no changes in the error message

Comment: @KenLee Did try changing the code line as you mentioned but still no change in the error

Comment: Is there a possibility that the hosting server is casuing the trouble, because the same exact code works fine on my local server

Comment: @KenLee Tried both ini_set('display_errors', 0); and error_reporting(0);

In this case the error message simply dissapers but the file is not getting downloaded, all it did was hid the error message from showing

Comment: The message says that empleavehis.php sends something at the first line. Check the beginning of that file.

Comment: The screenshot of Notepad++ shows an unsaved file and not the file where the output is triggered (empleavehis.php)

Comment: @JanSlabon I later tried saving the file and checked on the encoding still it was the same as before UTF-8, and the issue was not with that since the file was already in UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I shifted the whole fpdf code to the top of the php document and now it is getting downloaded. No changes to the code were done

Comment: In your question the file already begins with `<?php` ? How's it possible to move code more to the top then?

Comment: @JanSlabon I had a while loop in top of the FPDF code and the FPDF code was under that while loop, what i did was i removed the FPDF code from the while loop php tags and created a new php tag on the very top of the document (Just under <!DOCTYPE html> and added the FPDF code and closed the php tags. The rest of the code comes after that

Comment: For the next question, please provide ALL information and don't cut pieces out of a file. With the information that `<!DOCTYPE html>` is at the top of the file it would be much easier to tell you what's causing the output ;-)